# Training and Deploying my ML model on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I am getting difficulty in training and deploying my sci-kit learn model on Google Cloud Platform. Can someone suggest me what Google Cloud Products to use and how?

Comment: The question is too broad. If you have a specific question and provide more details about what you have done and what specific problem you are facing you would higher your chance of getting good response. Have a look at the [How do I ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

[Google Cloud Machine Learning Engine](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/) would most likely be the product you are looking for.

This quickstart guide should get you started: 
https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/scikit/quickstart

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/scikit/quickstart#train_and_save_a_model) is where it talks about how to export a model you have trained locally and then deploy it.